# go build caches intermediate build artifacts, how can I ignore some of them?

Tags: go, caching, build

I have a Go project which uses cgo to use native libraries. I need to test that package to make sure it works with different combinations of native libraries. To do so, I set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variables to different paths and run `go build` multiple times.

However, it seems that `go build` caches intermediate build artifacts, so the test results are not correct. `go build` has [-a](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/17bddc8bf4fdbe50ea67f75db5cddc3061b5000d/src/cmd/go/internal/work/build.go#L70) option to ignore the cache, but it seems to ignore all the cache. I want to ignore only some of the cache. Is there any way to do so? Or is there ways to set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` as a hash key for the go build cache?

Answer (score 0):

You could try cleaning the cache for package like

```bash
go clean -cache package/path/
```

and then go for

```bash
go build
```